# filter on hybrid properties with sqlalchemy with base classes

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, hybrid

In my sqlalchemy based app, I have 3 classes inheriting from a BASE class. Each of those has fields which describe the row, and then a list of attributes. I created a string representation for each row, after which I created a `hybrid_property` named `description` in the base class.

Obviously, when trying to filter on `description`, this fails as sqlalchemy fails to understand the meaning of `str(self)`. I suppose I need to implement an expression for description in the child classes. But that fails due to `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`.

How can I implement this in a DRY way?

```
class Base(object):
    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        """Generate the tablename programatically from the class name."""
        return cls.__name__.lower() + "s"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    @hybrid_property
    def description(self):
        """Return a description of the entry."""
        return str(self)


BASE = declarative_base(cls=Base)

class Environment(BASE):
    """Schema for environments table."""

    project = Column(String)
    version = Column(String)
    flavor = Column(String)
    environment = Column(String)
    some_attribute = Column(String)

    tests = relationship("Test", back_populates="environment",
                         cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")  

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation."""
        return (f"{self.project}-{self.version}-"
                f"{self.flavor}-{self.environment}")

    @BASE.description.expression
    def description(cls):
        return func.concat(cls.project, "-", cls.version, "-",
                           cls.flavor, "-", cls.environment)


class Test(BASE):
    """Schema for tests table."""

    environment_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("environments.id"))
    environment = relationship("Environment", back_populates="tests")
    name = Column(String)
    credits = Column(Integer)
    runs = relationship("Run", back_populates="test",
                        cascade="all, delete, delete-orphan")

    def __str__(self):
        """Return a string representation of test identifier."""
        return f"{self.environment}-{self.name}"

    @BASE.description.expression
    def description(cls):
        return func.concat(cls.environment.description(), "-", cls.name)
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable` shouldn't normally happen; this seems to indicate that you've overridden `str` somewhere in your code (doesn't appear in the code you posted though).

Comment: "Obviously when trying to filter on description, this fails ..." is not quite obvious at all and seems a bit XYish. Please provide a [mcve]. Also provide full tracebacks instead of just the message part of an exception.